# Internet explorer 9 jquery error when trying to select a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer

I'm trying to make a button to work in my `HYML` + `javascript` + `jquery` code, but `IE9` fails, `chrome` and `firefox` works good.

I'm using `jQuery` 2.1.1, so `IE9` is supported. In my own code `$("#myButton").click(function (e) {});` does not even get called on click.

I'm making a button with `<input type="button" id="myButtonID"/>` or with `<input id="myButton" type="submit" value="someValue" class="success radius button" />`, and I'm getting error at `this.select()` line in the following dynamically generated code.

```
var clicked = false;
$("input,textarea").click(function () {
     var length = document.getSelection().toString().length;
     if (length > 0) {
          event.preventDefault();
          document.selection.empty();
     }
     else {
          if (!clicked) {
              this.select();
              clicked = true;
          }
     }
});
```

Any ideas what should i do to solve this issue?

Comment: How to you select a button? Don't you want focus for a button?

Comment: instead of click look up jquery `.on` - your problem is most likely related to binding on a dynamic element - .on is a 'live' binding and will pick up new elements added dynamically